# How to access DOM of BrowserWindow from remote in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create an electron app that contains a button on the main process which loads a new `BrowserWindow` with the remote module on click.

I want a second button in this new `BrowserWindow` to use the `exec` command from `child_process`.

I try to `addEventListener` to the second button but it isn't able to access the DOM (only able to `getElementByID` of index.html)

main.js snippet

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
require('electron-reload')(__dirname)
.
.
.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   <button id="1" onclick="render()">Primary Click</button>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
     <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

renderer script (within main.js)

```
function render(){
  const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
  const { exec } = require("child_process")
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
  win.loadFile('index2.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.webContents.once("dom-ready", ()=>{
     document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", function(){
      exec("echo hello >> hello.txt") 
    })
  })
}
```

index2.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World2!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="2">Secondary Click</button>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I get the error:

`Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: HTML elements IDs cannot start with a number (at least in html4) `<button id="2">` try an alphabetical character

Comment: changing IDs to `one` and `two` for each button gives same error

Comment: you have to put the dom scripts inside the renderers js file , not in the main.js.